# javafx show progressindicator while loading

Tags: java, javafx

This is the main window of my application:

[image: screenshot]

I want to be able to update the window, so i wrote a method `reset` which ist triggered by pressing F5:

```
public void reset() {
    final ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(-1.0f);

    final HBox hb = new HBox(pi);
    final VBox vb = new VBox(hb);

    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    scene.setRoot(vb);

    //this.show();
}
```

if i run this it looks sth like this:

[image: screenshot]

However, if I uncomment the line `//this.show();` this will be executed:

```
public void show() {
    final VBox box = API_CALL_AND_BUILDING_BOX_MAGIC_WHICH_I_STRIPPED;

    gp.getChildren().clear();
    gp.getChildren().add(box);

    scene.setRoot(gp);
    stage.sizeToScene();
}
```

and I will never be able to see my ProgressIndicator because the application will just hang until the APIcall is finished and the new content is loaded.

I tried a bit with Threads and Platform.runLater() but I cant get it to work. My goal is to display the ProgressIndicator until the APIcall is finished, the box is build and the scene gets given `gp` as the new root.

I hope its somewhat understandable what my goal and my problems are :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another JVM thread dedicated to fetch data from the remote source. The main thread of your application must never block with network operations: in the keyboard event handler you just repaint the main window with the progress indicator and then wait for another event, that can be:

- background operation finished (successful, unsuccessful)
- user interrupts (mouse/keyboard)
- a timeout expires

Pseudocode with [ListenableFuture](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) by Guava

```
// Initialize in ctor use MoreExecutors
private final ListeningExecutorService service;

// Keep to call .cancel()
private ListenableFuture<APIData> currentRequest;

// Run in the GUI thread
public void onRefreshEvent() {
  showProgressIndicator();
  currentRequest = service.submit(/* Some Callable<APIData> */);
  Futures.addCallback(currentRequest , this, this);
}

// From FutureCallback<T>
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {} // TODO
public void onSuccess(APIData d) {}   // TODO

// From Executor
public void execute(Runnable cmd) {
  Platform.runLater(cmd);
}
```

<sub>Don't forget to consider socket connect and read timeout, as well as pooling HTTP connection! Also consider if the background task should check the interrupted flag</sub>

Comment: FFS how can I create a new line in a comment? :D

Comment: Ahh its shift + enter...

So what i wanted to say:

I got it to work, even though on a much more basic level then you suggested.

You're obviously operating some levels above me ;)

But I will now try to implement it they way you suggested!

Comment: Note that since this is a JavaFX question, the JavaFX API defines a specific [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class for this purpose; it provides an `updateProgress` method and other callback methods for interacting with the UI thread.